# Why an empty search in the GooglePlay will lead to "unicorns"?

Tags: google-play-store

Why is an [empty search request on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q) transformed in a search for "unicorns"?

This is the only Google service that allow you to make an empty search... to give you unicorns. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Google is known for their sense of humor and this just seems to be another example of one of their [Easter Eggs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_hoaxes_and_easter_eggs).

My guess is that when you do an empty search, you are searching for something that doesn't exist, so... why not unicorns?

Comment: Why not unicorns, indeed.